# Can't install Windows 10 on a Gigabyte Aorus Pro X399 motherboard

Tags: windows-10, drivers, raid, threadripper

I've built a Threadripper PC using the Gigabyte X399 Aorus Pro motherboard, and I'm trying to install Windows 10 on it.

I used Microsoft's Media Creation Tool in my old PC to create an ISO image, then burnt it to a DVD, and then booted the new PC with it. I should mention that I have set up my X399 PC's hard drives as RAID, in the following way:

- An SATA SSD as an independent volume. This will be my boot volume, where I intend to install Windows.
- Two mechanical SATA HDs as RAID 0.

Anyway, I boot up the new PC using my Windows 10 DVD... and I reach the step where it says that it needs drivers. The manual of my motherboard says to copy the drivers folder (`BootDrv\Hw10`) from the included DVD to a thumb drive, so that's what I do.
 I plug the thumb drive, and two entries appear, both of which say:

```
AMD-RAID Bottom Device
```

I click on it... but Windows says then that "it hasn't found any new device driver".

I uncheck the "Hide incompatible drivers" checkbox, and a number of new entries appear, one of which is called "`AMD-RAID Controller (storport)`". I try with that one, but Windows says the same: "no new device drivers found".

I checked at Gigabyte's website (https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X399-AORUS-PRO-rev-10#support-dl-driver-lan), but the newest drivers there are the same ones that I already have. My BIOS is also at the latest (actually, the only) revision.

What do I do now?

Comment: If you are installing to the RAID then you need to provide the RAID drivers.  It should be as simple as pointing to the provided `.inf ` file.

Comment: @Ramhound: um, that's exactly what I did. The "AMD-RAID Bottom Device" that I mentioned above is supposed to be exactly that, and yet Windows doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Is the SSD an NVMe drive by chance?

Comment: Nope. Forgot to mention that: everything is SATA.

Comment: You could always disconnect the drives, install Windows on the SSD, then once Windows is installed configure the RAID.  If you do it this way be sure to install the RAID drivers before you RAID with the BIOS

Comment: Ugh. I don't even know if I can actually do that. First I'd have to set the motherboard as AHCI, install Windows, and then set it up again as RAID... and I'm not sure whether this latter step deletes everything on the existing drives, including the Windows installation.

Comment: As long as you install the RAID drivers, before you switched it to RAID, you wouldn't have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound: well, I tried that... and it didn't work. Windows installs fine with the motherboard on AHCI, but once I've done that, I've found no way to make it switch to RAID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally got it solved. Guess what it was?

As mentioned above, I was installing Windows from an ISO created using Microsoft's Media Creation Tool, which was presumably for the latest version of Windows 10, and the problem was that the installer didn't recognize the RAID drivers supplied with the motherboard. I downloaded a full ISO image from MS's website for the previous version of Windows (1803, I believe) and tried...

At first, it gave me the same error while installing the `AMD-RAID Bottom Device` (rcbottom.inf) driver: "no new device drivers detected". But then I tried installing the next driver (the `AMD-RAID controller` one, rcraid.inf)... and it detected the RAID and worked perfectly. So now you know.

Of course, I wonder now what's going to happen when Windows connects to the Internet and tried to download the latest update...